# DateTime format issue

Tags: c#, .net

Why a slash is changed into dash while providing explicit date format (screen below) ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the slash represents the locale-specific date separator.  To insert a slash explicitly, you need to escape it.  See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DATETIME.TOSTRING%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy")
```